# is there an easy way to allow a private google cloud function talk to another private one without authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

i've read this:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing

but it's unclear to me how to achieve the following

- i have 2 functions A and B
- i want B to be reachable by A
- i want B NOT to be reachable from the internet
- A sends requests without authentication (i cannot change this)

so what i want to do is "accept internal calls, reject external calls"
how do i do this?
i have a working setup where A can call B successfully, but B is now public. how do i make it private?

i tried restricting access to "internal only" but then even in the cloud shell, my curls get a 403

Answer (score 2):

If you're not able to send some form of identity or authentication to function B, then no, there is no "easy" way to protect it in the way that you're describing.

The only supported way to do this is [using IAM to authorize access](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls) to ensure that B only accepts requests from entities that are authorized to do so.  You could also implement some custom authorization using additional code that you write, but IAM is the method that Google Cloud gives you natively.

You could also look into [using a VPC](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc) to isolate the network access of the functions, but I would not consider this "easy".

Comment: what is the "only internal traffic" option for?

Comment: i've never dealt with CFs before. so the correct settings are "allow all traffic" + "my calling function is an invoker"?

Comment: (and allow unauthenticated?)

Comment: The first link I provided (edited) explains how to enable access to a specific service account with the role required to invoke the function.  It does not involve allowing all traffic.